# How to center align column without borders

Tags: php, html, any

I'm currently working on a personal project where i use wordpress. Creating a page is flexible as there's an option to use codes. However, i'm having problem adjusting the a part of where i created a column (See photo)

[image: test1]

Would appreciate if someone can assist me on this. Thank you.

Comment: Use Photoshop and just cut and paste the bit of the image you want to move ... if you want help with the code that *creates* that image, try posting some code!

Comment: Without the code it will be hard ! But if it's only a css problem, look flexbox maybe. You need to make something like this : `.container { display: flex; justify-content: space-around;}` and all the child of your parent should be well placed. But again, without the code can't give you a clean solution !

Comment: You need a div block surrounding your images, once your images are well fit on your block you just need to put your block at the right place with margin autos... Would be nice indeed to have at least your html code!

Comment: You should add your CSS and HTML code to the question if you really want some help